# How to use Conditional Type Assignment for different integer types in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

[XSD1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-1-20120405/#dcl.elt.exx) allows the type of an element to depend on one of its attributes. For example,

```
<integer kind='s'>100</integer>
```

will cause the type of 'element' to be xs:short. Here is what I have got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
   <xs:complexType name="GenericInt">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
            <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:element name="integer" type="GenericInt">
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='b'" type="xs:byte"/>
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='s'" type="xs:short"/>
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='i'" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='l'" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:alternative                  type="GenericInt"/>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I tried to save the file in Altova XMLSpy, an error occurred:
    cos-st-derived-ok.2: Simple type definition 'xs:byte' is not validly derived from 'GenericInt'.

So how should I correct the XSD code?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be something like

```
    <xs:complexType name="GenericInt">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
            <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:assert test="(@kind='b' and $value = (-128 to 127))
                       or (@kind='s' and $value = (-32768 to 32767))
                       or (....)"/>
   </xs:complexType>
```

though you wouldn't get the precise PSVI type annotation that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
   <xs:complexType name="bInt">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:byte">
            <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="sInt">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:short">
            <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="iInt">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:int">
            <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="lInt">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:long">
            <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="gInt">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
            <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:element name="integer">
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='b'" type="bInt"/>
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='s'" type="sInt"/>
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='i'" type="iInt"/>
      <xs:alternative test="@kind='l'" type="lInt"/>
      <xs:alternative                  type="gInt"/>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Any better solution?

Comment: My instinct would be to define the various complex types sInt etc as restrictions of the complex type GenericInt, but it's still going to be very verbose, because restricting complex types always is.